# Python: passing a constant as method parameter

Tags: python, parameters, constants

I want to pass a class name to a method as a constant.

Example:

```
def foo(Bar):
   # ...
```

Eventually, I want to be able to use **Bar** as a class name in method **foo**

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Usually there is no need to pass a constant as an argument to a function.

Comment: What you mean by *"pass a class name to a method as a constant"* ? And also by *"use Bar as a class name in method foo"* ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass class as an argument to function. Below is the example to prove it.

```
class Bar():
    @staticmethod   # created staticmethod; can be call without creating the object
    def my_print():
        print 'Hello, I am class function'

def foo(my_class):
    my_class().my_print()  # call my_print() of the object passed

foo(Bar) # Pass class "Bar" as argument to "foo()"
# prints: Hello, I am class function
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

```
class Bar():
    pass

def foo(param):
    print "class_name is {}".format(param.__name__) #prints class name

foo(Bar)
```